# Como fazer um in em lambda?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma função `convertStringListaInt` com parametro `String`.

Exemplo :

String: *1,2*.

Estou convertendo essa string em uma *List* do tipo `convertStringListaInt_Result` tendo como propriedade `number`(inteiro).

Como posso fazer um `in` usando *Lambda*?

Percebi o Entity aceita somente tipos primitivos na comparação e que por isso o erro é gerado.

*Código:*

```
public static bool ExisteAIPR(string IDEscopo) {
       using(entidadesIUS entidades = new entidadesIUS()) {
       List <convertStringListaInt_Result> resultado = entidades.convertStringListaInt(IDEscopo).ToList();
       return entidades.Escopos.Where(e => resultado.Select(x => x.number).Contains(e.IDEscopo) && e.AIPR == "S").FirstOrDefault() != null ? true : false;
   }
}
```

**Erro Gerado**

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'Modelo.DTO.convertStringListaInt_Result'. Only primitive types or
>   enumeration types are supported in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que está na pergunta, estou supondo que `convertStringListaInt_Result` deva ser algo assim:

```
public class convertStringListaInt_Result 
{
    ...
    public int number { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

A lógica está quase certa, só que usando `.Select(x => x.number)` você está devolvendo um inteiro, e a ideia é que se devolva uma lista de inteiros. `Contains` é operado em cima de uma lista, e não em cima de cada elemento.

Para este caso, você teria que usar `ToList`, e não apenas `Select`. `Select` devolve uma função geradora do tipo do elemento colocado no predicado, e não a lista em si. Ficaria algo assim:

```
    public static bool ExisteAIPR(string IDEscopo)
    {
        using (entidadesIUS entidades = new entidadesIUS())
        {
            List<int> resultado = entidades.convertStringListaInt(IDEscopo).Select(x=> x.number).ToList(); 
            return entidades.Escopos.Where(e => resultado.Contains(e.IDEscopo) 
&& e.AIPR == "S").FirstOrDefault() != null;
        }
    }
```

Ou ainda, aproveitando a primeira versão da resposta, você pode modificar o método `convertStringListaInt` pra devolver uma lista de inteiros:

```
 public static bool ExisteAIPR(string IDEscopo)
    {
        using (entidadesIUS entidades = new entidadesIUS())
        {
            List<int> resultado = entidades.convertStringListaInt(IDEscopo).ToList();
            return entidades.Escopos.Where(e => resultado.Contains(e.IDEscopo) && e.AIPR == "S").FirstOrDefault() != null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Marconi Entra aqui: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha