# Contains dentro de uma lista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho Uma lista de Ativos que contem uma lista de Acessórios

Gostaria de filtrar todos os Ativos que os acessórios(ID_ACESSORIOS) estão dentro de uma lista de int.

Segue o código;

```
//Lista com todos os ID_ACESSORIOS que tenho que filtrar
List<int> idAcessoriosFiltro = model.AcessoriosFiltroList.Where(a => a.Selecionado == true).Select(b => b.ID_ACESSORIO).ToList();

//A variavel retorno contem todos os ativos que preciso filtrar
List<Ativo> retorno = _Service.FiltrarAtivos(Mapper.Map<RelatorioAtivosFiltroViewModel, AtivoFiltro>(model));
```

Comment: Usando `List<int>` ? Isso não é JavaScript, certo? Qual a linguagem?

Comment: Desculpa, editei

Comment: a um tempo atrás perguntei [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38986/como-fazer-um-in-em-lambda), talvez possa te ajudar!

Comment: Nessa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/186100/5846) eu comento a respeito também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tente o seguinte:

```
 retorno.Where(w => 
     w.Acessorios.Any(a => idAcessoriosSelect.Contains(a.ID_ACESSORIO)
 ).ToList();
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não amigo, acho que me expressei errado, vamos lá.

idAcessoriosSelect  = Filtro que vem da View com os id dos acessorios escolhidos.

retorno = Ativos (retorno do banco de dados) cada ativo tem uma lista de acessórios. cada acessório tem um ID_ACESSORIO, preciso pegar todos os acessorios cujo id_ACESSORIO esteja dentro da minha (idAcessoriosSelect)

Comment: @JuniorTorres você quer aplicar este filtro entre as listas idAcessoriosSelect e retorno, certo?

Comment: (idAcessoriosFiltro) é Filtro         (retorno) é a lista que tem que ser filtrada.

Comment: @juniortorres feitos ajustes na resposta.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Caso você não tenha uma restrição para usar LINQ, talvez a expressão abaixo ajude.

```
List<int> idAcessoriosSelect = (from f in model.AcessoriosFiltroList where f.Selecionado == true select f.ID_ACESSORIO).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var lAtivos = retorno.Where(c=> c.lAcessorios.where(cI => idAcessoriosFiltro.Any(cI.Id))).ToList();
```

retorno sua lista de ativos, lAcessorios a lista de acessorios interna.